# How send email with name with third party domain?

Tags: linux, email, unix, sendmail

Is it possible to send email with address name with third party domain?

For example to send email with address name: `my_email@google.com` using Linux environment?

Comment: The `From:` header is always filled by the emailclient. You can use `From: Santa@Cla.us` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mailx utility can do this. Below is the example:

Suppose CONTENT is a variable storing the content.

```
echo $CONTENT | mailx -r FROM_EMAIL_ID -s "SUBJECT" TO_EMAIL_ID
```

Else, you want to pass a file having mail body named CONTENT.txt,

```
mailx -r FROM_EMAIL_ID -s "SUBJECT" TO_EMAIL_ID < CONTENT.txt
```